# Isa relationship query in sql

Tags: sql

I have a disjoint relationship among my tables: `Employee(empId PK, name), HourlyEmployee(empId PK FK, hourlySalary)` `empId` is a reference to `Employee.empId`,

`MonthlyEmployee(empId Pk FK, monthlySalary)` `empId` is a reference to `Employee.empId`.

How can I create a query resulting `AllEmployees(empId,name,hourlySalary,monthlySalary).`

For all hourly employees monthlySalary will be null and for all monthly employess hourly salary will be null

Regards,
Tural

Comment: Show us your query...What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use outer joins to get all employees no matter if they exist in HourlyEmployee or MonthlyEmployee (or neither of them).

```
select e.empid, e.name, h.hourlysalary, m.monthlysalary
from employee e
left outer join hourlyemployee h on h.empid = e.empid
left outer join monthlyemployee m on m.empid = e.empid;
```

Comment: So, left outer join means keep everything in the left table (first table) and put null if there no appropriate value in the right table(second table). Is this understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.empid, e.name, h.hourlysalary, m.monthlysalary
from employee e
left outer join hourlyemployee h on h.empid = e.empid
left outer join monthlyemployee m on m.empid = e.empid
where (h.hourlysalary is null) or (m.monthlysalary is null);
```